# How to configure Network Interfaces on ubuntu in virtual Boxes?

Tags: networking, vmware, virtualization, virtualbox-networking

**The Question**

How can ubuntu be configured so that you don't got the "waiting for network configuration..." message at boot if you got ***more than one adapter?***

**Facts**

- I've got an untouched Ubuntu here in Virtual Box and In VM-Ware Workstation.
- My `/etc/network/interfaces` file is untouched and I've activated a Nat adapter to use the host systems real network card.
- Additionally I've activated a host only adapter to be able to use a separate IP for connections between the VM and the host system.

**Deduction**

I figured out that the interfaces file needs only one gateway entry and this is given trough

`auto eth0`

`iface eth0 inet dhcp`.

So this is the entry for the first network adapter that provides gateway information and so the second configuration has no need for a line called

`gateway 192.168.1.1`.

For me that means the second entry has to look like this:

`address 192.168.217.131`

depending on what the router tells you as network address for the interface configured trough dcp and the second line here is the netmask. In common cases this is

`netmask 255.255.255`.

So the entire `/etc/network/interfaces'-file looks like this:

```
#This file describe the network interfaces available on your system
#and how to activate them. For more information see interfaces(5).

#The loopack network interface 

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#The primary network interface 

# ethernet 0
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static

address 192.168.217.131
netmask 255.255.255

#No need for gateway here because this is already provided by the dhcp entry.
```

In this example I've taken the IP address provided by Ubuntu's ^server (Basic Ubuntu Server) package what was 192.168.217.130 and increased it by one.

Now I restart Ubuntu and got the message `Waiting for network Configuration...` where Ubuntu try to wait for network connection about 2 minutes.

I've had the same on Virtual Box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things to know

1. As already mentioned above there is no need for a second gateway with a dhcp server in your network because the gateway entry is generated from there.
2. After you've added a host-onely adapter you have to copy the ip-adress from your windows host.

So far.

Here is an example configuration for a host only connection with one additional adapter:

```
auto eth1

iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.253.128
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.253.1
broadcast 192.168.253.255
```

The Third block of the network line depends on your ip.
the broadcast line is needed for network communication between the host and the guest. This is a networking protocol related thing.

Comment: NO, you do not have to copy the IP address of the host. You can simply set any IP address to your VM with a host only network option.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to connect your VM to your home network with deferent ip than host system then you should choose **Bridge** option.  In this advance options you need to choose **allow to all**  for communications between VM to host, Vm to Vm.

You need to choose Bridge connection for second Network Adapter. You also need to configure `dns-nameservers` and `gateway` as this Network Adapter is different from first.

Here in your configuration file **netmask** should be

```
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Something extra would be neccessary for networking to be up and running on some occasions. Providing dns-nameservers in /etc/network/interfaces file instead of '/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base' file. 
Example:

```
auto eth1

iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.217.131
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.217.1
broadcast 192.168.217.255
gateway 'provide your gateway here might be necessary'
dns-nameservers 'provide your nameserver here'
```

Finally,

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `dns-nameservers` option, couldn't get updates without it.